# If $X$ is path connected, $\pi(X,x)\cong\pi(X,y)\ \forall x,y\in X$: a categorical intepretation

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, intuition, fundamental-groups

It is a well known fact that if $X$ is a topological space where there exist a path with endpoints $x,y\in X$ then the fundamental group of the pointed spaces $(X,x)$ and $(X,y)$ are isomorphic, though not 'canonically', in the sense that the isomoprhism is directly induced by the path mattered.

As a simple consequence, if $X$ is path connected the fact holds for any choice of $x,y\in X$.

I was wondering if we can translate this result in a statement about the fundamental group functor. In fact, the path *induces* an isomorphism between groups, anyhow the path itself is not a morphism of the category of pointed topological spaces. So intuitively there is a functorial flavour, which I do not if can be made precise.

Moreover one can prove that the isomorphism is path independent hence 'canonical' if and only if the fundamental group is abelian. Also in this case, I wonder if there is a nice categorical intepretation.

Comment: I don't know if you find this categorical, but a better object than $\pi_1(X,x)$ is the fundamental *groupoid* $\Pi_1(X)$. The existence of a path $x\to y$ in this setting amounts to an isomorphism between two objects in this groupoid, and then the facts you state are general (easy) facts about groupoids.

Comment: It is straightforward to prove the isomorphism is canonical iff the group is abelian. You should try.

Comment: @ConnorMalin yes I know the proof, just wondering about an interpretation of this fact

Comment: I agree with Max. See the book "Topology and Groupoids".